# CSS expression for "screen height - (header + footer height)"

Tags: css

I have a HTML page which contains `<header>`, `<section>` and `<footer>`. And I want to set section min-height to `screen height - (header + footer height)`. Is that possible?

```
section{
    min-height: screen-height-(header + footer height)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use preprocessors. SASS/LESS/Stylus.

**LESS Example:**

```
@base: 5%;
@filler: @base * 2;
@other: @base + @filler;

color: #888 / 4;
background-color: @base-color + #111;
height: 100% / 2 + @filler;
```

[LESS Docs link](http://lesscss.org/features/#features-overview-feature-operations)

However, if you want to have manipulations based on screen height, preprocessors can't detect screen height, you will have to use JavaScript/jQuery for that.